# Access Image type using string

Tags: c#, wpf, image, controls

So i have `i` images, and I set the images names in code like

```
image.Name = "Image" + i;
```

i want to access all `i` images so i can change its property and bind it. I use this code :

```
for (int i = 1; i < itotal; i++)
{
    Binding binding = new Binding
    {
        Source = AtextBox,
        Path = new PropertyPath("Text"),
    };
    Image imagex = (Image)this.FindName("Image" + i);
    xImage = imagex;
    xImage.SetBinding(ContentControl.OpacityProperty, binding);
}
```

But i can't get the imagex, its value keep null. Why? What is the right way to do it?

Comment: What is `this` in above code ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad eh i think its a frameworkElement

Comment: And in which control does images reside ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad the images is in canvas, i add it using `canvas.children.add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add elements to a parsed element trees. To do that you need to 
you need to call [`RegisterName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.inamescope.registername.aspx).

```
// ...
image.Name = "Image" + i;
this.RegisterName(image.Name, image);

// ...

for (int i = 1; i < itotal; i++)
{
    Binding binding = new Binding
    {
        Source = AtextBox,
        Path = new PropertyPath("Text"),
    };
    Image imagex = (Image)this.FindName("Image" + i);
    xImage = imagex;
    xImage.SetBinding(ContentControl.OpacityProperty, binding);
}
```

Comment: i tried this `this.RegisterName("Image" + i, image);` and it is a void (i got error that cannot convert void to Image), and i cant assign it to a variable that i want to use it.

Comment: yes it works, i got another problem from this though. but this is works, thank you